# I can not download gpx from GPS through GPS tool with GPS babel on QGIS

Tags: gps, gpsbabel

I have already install GPS tool plug-in and GPS Babel.
Garmin GPS map 62s is connected my PC through USB cable.

I changed device setting according to below site.
http://nickmcw.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/quantum-gis-using-a-usb-gps-device/

I set below condition on "Download from GPS"tab.
GPS device: Garmin USB( ←I create by myself)
Port:usb
Feature type:way point
Layer name:F:\Garmin\GPX
output file:test

At least, I got new GPX file on layer of QGIS.

Altgough the new GPX file is expected include existing gpx information from GPS, there is no row in attribute table.

Colum names were put automatically.followings are.
Name/elevation/symbol/comment/description/source・・・・・

Why I can not get gpx file from GPS???

Comment: You might care to mark some of the answers to your previous questions as "answered".

Answer (score 1):

I think the instruction you followed were meant for "old" GPS devices. With a GPSmap 62, you do not have to use gpsbabel at all to download your data. They are already stored as gpx-files on the device.

After plugging the GPS device, use your file browser and navigate to your gpx files on the device, and dragndrop them into the map canvas of QGIS. There will be a prompt where you can choose which types of data you want to import (waypoints, tracks, tracktpoints etc).

Waypoints and tracks are stored in different gpx-files.
To work with that data, you should then save the layers as shp to your project.

Answer (score 0):

In GPS Babel, if you haven't already, check the transation option tracks or try nmea sentences.
Are you using a map format that is compatible output for your device?
I might try filter formats such as track or arc.
Read the documentation, especialy the sections of interest an relevance such as garmin usb serial protocol. A lot of applications call gpsbabel, see if one of those may work as well, even though live tracking into the gis is more usefull since you get the shp. of the rte. trk. file easily then.
Read the gps documentation in qgis on gps live tracking as well, experiment. GPS is often about debugging, developement, and file conversions.